# Keep getting syntax error running Google Apps script to import individual google form links into google (responses) sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Keep getting syntax error running Google Apps script to import individual google form links into google (responses) sheet. Can anyone identify the issue?

Please see the script:

```
function assignEditUrls() {
var form = FormApp.openById('1FyNUeFk_bEqraE9TNLbFMQimKtp93mInqPP6IhJDJ_s');

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Form Responses 1');

var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
var urlCol = 87;
var responses = form.getResponses();
var timestamps = [], urls = [], resultUrls = [];

for (var i = 0; i < responses.length; i++) {
 timestamps.push(responses[i].getTimestamp().setMilliseconds(0));
 urls.push(responses[i].getEditResponseUrl());

for (var j = 1; j < data.length; j++) {
 
 resultUrls.push([data[j][0]?urls[timestamps.indexOf(data[j][0].setMilliseconds(0))]:""]);
 
 sheet.getRange(2, urlCol, resultUrls.length).setValues(resultUrls);
 }
```

Comment: About `syntax error`, I think that in your showing script, your function and for loop are not enclosed by `}`. How about this?

Comment: Please add the textual error message.

Answer (score 0):

I think this:

```
for (var j = 1; j < data.length; j++) {
 resultUrls.push([data[j][0]?urls[timestamps.indexOf(data[j][0].setMilliseconds(0))]:""]); 
 sheet.getRange(2, urlCol, resultUrls.length).setValues(resultUrls);
 }
```

Should be

```
   for (var j = 1; j < data.length; j++) {
     resultUrls.push([data[j][0]?urls[timestamps.indexOf(data[j][0].setMilliseconds(0))]:""]);
     }
   }
   sheet.getRange(2, urlCol, resultUrls.length).setValues(resultUrls);
 }
```

You should only have to do the setValues() once